# Dynamically change properties of a text element outside the View Controller in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am new to Swift and mobile development, recently I have been trying to create a piece of code that can work independently on top of IOS Apps. My goal is to create a framework that can manipulate the styling of text in all apps.

What I am stuck at is how to access and dynamically change the properties of a text element inside a view controller.

Is it possible to create a framework that can look inside View Controllers and dynamically change style?

So far what I have achieved is manipulating the font style and color with a function written outside the view controller(planning to dump that to a framework later).

It's my 3rd-day learning swift, sorry for any silly code or questions. I searched a lot on how to dynamically access elements inside view controller but did not find anything..

Here is my code

```
//
//  ContentView.swift
//  Swift-UI-Test
//
//  Created by Vikas Nair on 08/05/21.
//

import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var stateObject = TestObject()

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 20){
            Text("Vikku Here")
            .foregroundColor(changeBkColor(color: stateObject.color))
                .fontWeight(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.bold/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                .font(.system(size:CGFloat(textsize(text_size: stateObject.font_size)) ))
            Button(action: {
                        
                stateObject.color = 2
                stateObject.font_size = "med"
                        
                    }) {
                Text("Press")
                .frame(width: 60, height: 60)
                .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                .background(Color.blue)
                .clipShape(Circle())
             }.buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
            
            Button(action: {
                        
                stateObject.color = 3
                stateObject.font_size = "big"
                        
                    }) {
                Text("Press")
                .frame(width: 60, height: 60)
                .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                .background(Color.blue)
                .clipShape(Circle())
             }.buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
        
    }
}
}

class TestObject: ObservableObject {
    @Published var color: Int = 1
    @Published var font_size: String = "small"
}

func changeBkColor(color: Int) -> Color
{
    if(color == 1)
    {
        return Color.red;
    }
    else if(color == 2)
    {
        return Color.green;
    }
    else if(color == 3)
    {
        return Color.blue;
    }
    else
    {
        return Color.black;
    }
}


func textsize(text_size: String)-> Float
{
    if(text_size == "big")
    {
        return 60.0;
    }
    else if(text_size == "med")
    {
        return 35.0;
    }
    else if(text_size == "small")
    {
        return 20.0;
    }
    else
    {
        return 10.0;
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I would do:

1. Change `@StateObject var stateObject = TestObject()` to `@EnvironmentObject var testObject: TestObject`.
2. Get rid of `changeBkColor(color:)`. You don't need it.
3. Make `TestObject`'s `color` property a `Color`, like this: `@Published var color: Color = Color.red`.
4. Change `.foregroundColor(changeBkColor(color: stateObject.color))` to `.foregroundColor(testObject.color)`.
5. Store a reference to your `TestObject` in your `SceneDelegate`, and in your `SceneDelegate`'s `scene(_:willConnectTo:options:)` function, set the `.environmentObject`, like this:

```
static let testObject = TestObject()
    

    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        let contentView = ContentView()

        if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
            let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
            window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: contentView.environmentObject(SceneDelegate.testObject)) // <-- Here
            self.window = window
            window.makeKeyAndVisible()
        }
    }
```

Then, just set `TestObject`'s `color` property to a `Color` to change the color of the text.